# xsi:type attribute does not bound to any namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, xsi, xsitype

I am trying to generate an xml from a response xml using a style sheet. But not able to generate the desired outcome. It seems the issue is with the xsi:type attribute. Can anybody suggest a possible change in the style sheet.

**Source XML**

```
   <soapenv:Body>
  <searchResponse>
     <platformCore:searchResult xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformCore:status isSuccess="true"/>
        <platformCore:totalRecords>17403</platformCore:totalRecords>
        <platformCore:pageSize>1000</platformCore:pageSize>
        <platformCore:totalPages>18</platformCore:totalPages>
        <platformCore:pageIndex>1</platformCore:pageIndex>
        <platformCore:searchId>WEBSERVICES_3479023_SB2_050620156958981381039449122_c4911d7b</platformCore:searchId>
        <platformCore:searchRowList>
           <platformCore:searchRow xsi:type="listAcct:ItemSearchRow" xmlns:listAcct="urn:accounting_2015_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
              <listAcct:basic xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                 <platformCommon:internalId>
                    <platformCore:searchValue internalId="2298"/>
                 </platformCommon:internalId>
                 <platformCommon:itemId>
                    <platformCore:searchValue>00411335</platformCore:searchValue>
                 </platformCommon:itemId>
                 <platformCommon:quantityAvailable>
                    <platformCore:searchValue>3721.0</platformCore:searchValue>
                 </platformCommon:quantityAvailable>
                 <platformCommon:quantityOnHand>
                    <platformCore:searchValue>3721.0</platformCore:searchValue>
                 </platformCommon:quantityOnHand>
              </listAcct:basic>
           </platformCore:searchRow>
           <platformCore:searchRow xsi:type="listAcct:ItemSearchRow" xmlns:listAcct="urn:accounting_2015_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
              <listAcct:basic xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                 <platformCommon:internalId>
                    <platformCore:searchValue internalId="20284"/>
                 </platformCommon:internalId>
                 <platformCommon:itemId>
                    <platformCore:searchValue>0117022</platformCore:searchValue>
                 </platformCommon:itemId>
                 <platformCommon:quantityAvailable>
                    <platformCore:searchValue>545.0</platformCore:searchValue>
                 </platformCommon:quantityAvailable>
                 <platformCommon:quantityOnHand>
                    <platformCore:searchValue>551.0</platformCore:searchValue>
                 </platformCommon:quantityOnHand>
              </listAcct:basic>
           </platformCore:searchRow>
```

.................
.................

**Desired Outcome**

```
<soapenv:Body>
<updateList>
  <updateItem>
     <itemCode></itemCode>
     <quantityOnHand></quantityOnHand>
  </updateItem>
  <updateItem>
     <itemCode></itemCode>
     <quantityOnHand></quantityOnHand>
  </updateItem>
  <updateItem>
     <itemCode></itemCode>
     <quantityOnHand></quantityOnHand>
  </updateItem>

  ................
  ........

</updateList>
```

The itemCode and quantityOnHand element will hold the value of platformCommon:itemId and platformCommon:quantityOnHand element of origina response.

Below is the XSL file I am using.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
    xmlns:listAcct="urn:accounting_2015_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com"
    xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:soapenv ="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Body>
  <updateList>
   <xsl:for-each select="soapenv:Body/searchResponse/platformCore:searchResult/platformCore:searchRowList/platformCore:searchRow">
     <updateItem>
     <itemCode>     
      <xsl:value-of select="listAcct:basic/platformCommon:itemId/platformCore:searchValue"/>
     </itemCode>    
     <quantityOnHand>     
      <xsl:value-of select="listAcct:basic/platformCommon:itemId/platformCore:searchValue"/>
     </quantityOnHand>
     </updateItem>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </updateList>
  </soapenv:Body> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That is because the attribute `type` is bound to `xsi` namespace. Your source XML is invalid. It should declare the `xsi` namespace.

Comment: Yes right..i did the same btw

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do to your stylesheet to make it accept ill-formed XML. The XML source contains

```
<platformCore:searchRow xsi:type="listAcct:ItemSearchRow"
 xmlns:listAcct="urn:accounting_2015_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
```

and the xsi prefix isn't declared. You need to fix the XML.